# Android WebView App displays white screen after clicking a link

Tags: android, android-webview

Masters,

I have a question. I've been building an Android App using WebView. Inside the app are links that navigates to external pages(I don't have any control with the WebSite that is loaded inside webview). I have an issue when I clicked a link and logCat returns : `I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"` App displays white screen only. Have you experienced this issue before? Are there any possible solutions? TIA

Comment: Can you open that link on PC browser?

Comment: When I tried it on the PC browser it didn't load and on the browser console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` is showed.

Comment: So this is not `WebView` trouble.

Comment: Yes, but the App displays white screen when the link is clicked. And logCat doesn't display any error except for the above mentioned.

Comment: this looks like a problem on the web page. probably some javascript stuff that's not working / crashing. this might also be the reason why the screen stays empty. can you look at the source code of the page in the browser?

Comment: share your code for webview. 
Is your url working in some browser of your mobile.

Comment: @dedda1994 I don't have any access to the JavaScript code of the page being loaded to the WebView

Comment: share your android code you are using for webview

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the extent of the problem

What you currently have problem is with

> Inside the app are links that navigates to external pages.

I have an
issue when I clicked a link and logCat returns

Comment: Yes, I dont the control of the external pages.

Comment: There isn't an element on your page with the id "" when your callback is being executed.

Comment: like i said, I dont have any control of the page that is loaded in the webView. And `onReceivedError` method does not return any info about the error. It just displays white screen.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't shared your code both for webview(Android) or html code.

As I am faced similar type of problem, So these are method which solved my problems

Method 1:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {

    view.loadUrl(urlNewString); // you are using siteView here instead of view
    return true;
}
```

Method 2: use http in url

Make sure the url starts with http://.
 Without http it will just show white screen.